# http request sent by python docker container heard and responded to by another container, but first container doesn't hear response

Tags: python-2.7, rest, docker, http, port

Am trying to build docker image for deploying automated testing of a python application restful API.  Am running the application using docker-compose which builds several containers (webserver, backend server, database, nginx, etc).  Have a separate python/pytest application that HTTPs to the target application (through the nginx container)
When running pytest locally pointing to the url for the containers, all is well.
When running from the docker container built from the testing repo dockerfile, all of the requests are heard and responded to by the backend service.  The nginx container logs show the correct calls and the expected response codes.  The backend container log shows that the calls were received and responded to.
The pytest container fails with `...python2.7/site-packages/future/utils/__init__.py:456: RestRequestException`

I'm new to Docker and don't yet know how to get back to the place throwing the error.

Here is environment information (the docker container pytest run):

```
root@17ad466cd12f:/code/app# pytest -vvvvv
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.9, pytest-4.3.0, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.12.0 -- /root/.pyenv/versions/2.7.9/bin/python2.7
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /code/app, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: pspec-0.0.3, tavern-0.26.4
```

Two basic questions:
1. Suggestions for how to proceed?
2. Anyone else seen this?  It looks like the testing container can't hear the responses from the application endpoints.

After trying some things (blindly) the nginx container is no longer listening to http calls from the pytest container.  now just getting

```
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.dev.bdev.us', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v2/profiles/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fcddede8550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM bepress/build-base-python:2.7.9

ENV API_TEST_SERVICE  .dev.bdev.us

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  python-virtualenv \
  python-argparse \
  nano \
  curl \
  git

CMD bash

# Switch to Python 2.7.9 globally
RUN pyenv global 2.7.9
RUN pip install pip --upgrade
RUN pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed six setuptools
RUN pip install ndg-httpsclient pyasn1 pyOpenSSL

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code
RUN pip install --ignore-installed -r requirements.txt --cache-dir /pip-cache
WORKDIR /code/app
ADD . /code/app
EXPOSE 80 
EXPOSE 443
```

Run command:

```
docker run --name egs-api-tests -i python2 bash
```

Trying to listen to responses to http requests from an nginx container that publishes ports 80 and 443.

Trying -p 443:443 or -p 80:80 throws error that ports are already in use.

From the container ping to google.com works, to api.dev.bdev.us (the url to the nginx service container)

Comment: You even not post a code which we can have a look...

Comment: Not sure what code to post.  What would help?

Comment: Have posted some code and output.

Comment: Have added more code and detail and a solution to the stated question.
Still working on the direct connection to the database in the db container from the test container

Answer (score 0):

The container I'm trying to connect to is part of a docker-compose group of containers that comprise the application under test. The docker-compose builds a network of the app containers (swng-dev_default) that I can now link my api testing container to. HTTP now works round trip.

```
docker run --name egs-api-tests -i --network swng-dev_default python2 bash
```

All good except I need direct access to the database (postgres in container called swng-dev_swng_db_1 database name = content_service)

So this question is resolved.

Just need to figure out what psycopg2 needs to send or the db container needs to accept.  (port 5432 is published by the db container (0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp.)